# Apply relationships to coefficients

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, rule

I have the following sum:
`s = Sum[Sum[Sum[Sum[A[i][j][k][l],{k,-10,10}],{j,-10,10}],{l,0,4}],{i,0,4}]`
where the number of terms is where the number of terms is `Length[s]=11025`.

But I have the following relation:

$A[\ x\ ][\ j \ ][\ k \ ][\ y\ ]=A[\ x\ ][\ -j \ ][\ k \ ][\ y\ ]=A[\ x\ ][\ j \ ][\ -k \ ][\ y\ ]=A[\ x\ ][\ -j \ ][\ -k \ ][\ y\ ] $

How can I apply the na rule in the expression to simplify the sum?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One note, layered sums can have their iterators collected into a single `Sum`:

```
bigsum = Sum[
   a[i, j, k, l], {i, 0, 4}, {l, 0, 4}, {j, -10, 10}, {k, -10, 10}];

Length[bigsum]
```

> 11025

This is equivalent to the original expression, though represented without currying. You may restore it to `a[i][j][k][l]` if it's more convenient for you, this answer only tangentially depends on the chosen pattern.

First option: directly applying the rule to the original answer:

```
bigsum2 = 
  bigsum //. {a[x_, j_ /; j < 0, k_, y_] :> a[x, -j, k, y], 
    a[x_, j_, k_ /; k < 0, y_] :> a[x, j, -k, y]};
```

This collects all possible $a[i][j][k][l]$ into a non-negative-argument canonical form. `//.` is repeated replacement, since it is possible for both $j$ and $k$ to be negative, but `/.` (`ReplaceAll`) will normally only apply one of the rules. `ReplaceRepeated` will perform replacements until the result stops changing, so it will catch that.

Second option: alter the sum to incorporate the rule directly using `Abs`:

```
bigsum3 = 
  Sum[a[i, Abs[j], Abs[k], l], {i, 0, 4}, {l, 0, 4}, {j, -10, 
    10}, {k, -10, 10}];
```

This also collects all the values into a non-negative-argument canonical form. You can prove that this is equivalent to `bigsum2` by using `Simplify` (e.g. `Simplify[bigsum3 - bigsum2] == 0`)

Option three: split the sum along the +/0/- axes:

```
bigsum4 = 
  Sum[a[i, 0, 0, l] + 2 Sum[a[i, j, 0, l], {j, 1, 10}] + 
    2 Sum[a[i, 0, k, l], {k, 1, 10}] + 
    4 Sum[a[i, j, k, l], {j, 1, 10}, {k, 1, 10}], {i, 0, 4}, {l, 0, 
    4}];
```

Note that the `a[i, 0, 0, l]` has a multiplicity of 1, the `a[i,j,0,l]` and `a[i,0,k,l]` terms have a multiplicity of 2 (since $j$ and $k$ can be positive or negative but collect to one or the other), and the `a[i,j,k,l]` non-zero terms have a multiplicity of 4 ($j$ and $k$ can both be positive or negative, leaving 4 choices to be collected into 1 term).

Again, this is the same result, though not identical in the form of the output -- `Simplify` is required this time to show that `Simplify[bigsum4 - bigsum2] == 0`.